# MacOS: difference between orange dot next to control center vs. to the right of clock?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, privacy

I've noticed that sometimes the orange dot for mic use* shows up right next to the control center icon (image 1) and sometimes it shows up farther to the right (image 2), in the very corner of the screen. The dot is usually (always?) in the corner when the computer is on the lock screen, but while I'm using the computer the dot can be in either place. Why does it move? Does it indicate anything?

MacBook Air 2021, OS 12.2.1

* I'm also having the problem where the dot stays on continuously, even when no apps are shown as currently or recently using the mic. It's probably caused by Zoom somehow [shakes fist] but I don't know if it's related to the dot moving around.

[image: orange dot next to control center 1]
[image: orange dot in corner of screen 2]

Comment: The dot moving around isn't significant, but I'm not writing this as an "answer" because I don't know why it moves.

Comment: Have you updated Zoom? A recent update is supposed to fix this.

Comment: I did install that update, and it did not fix it.

Comment: Same question; was recently on a Zoom call, but I don't see it in the activity monitor.

Comment: Several restarts and an OS update later, the problem has gone away, but I'm still curious about the moving dot.

Comment: I've got the same after installing and running Ableton. After restart the dot next to the clock (right) was gone. I haven't found what the dot means. I know what does mean the dot next to control center icon.

Comment: It is zoom. Tried joining a meeting with audio on, stays there for 1-2 sec with mic on, closed the meeting and its gone.
Also Happened with my camera dot indicator few days back.

Answer (score 4):

For any one who is searching, the dot indicates that microphone is being used. When the mic is being used, it shows like the first image. If you make some app fullscreen (like watching youtube video fullscreen), then it moves to the right.

But it's a bug that it's not disappear or continue staying like in image 2 even after no fullscreen app is on.

Comment: The dot also moves to the corner if something would otherwise cover it up. Normal windows can't cover up the menubar but some can, including the Zoom chat window. That still doesn't explain my stiuation, though.